# PHP - Is it ok to have your classes do all the work and not do much with the script using the class?

Tags: php, oop, class

This is just an opinion question but I don't want to elicit debate.  I just want professional feedback on whether it's good practice or bad practice to have your classes do all the work to where you just need to instantiate the object.  if everything goes well, then you do the next step whatever it is in your application, within the class.  If something goes wrong, you create a function to emit the errors within the class also.

I do all of this with the magic __construct method, and all my properties are private (or protected if i need to extend something)... most of my methods are private/protected also, except for getters and setters which i don't use much anyway, since everything happens inside the class.

For example, I have a login class, and you just feed it the username and password parameters when you instantiate it, and everything happens with the __construct I don't need to do anything with my script using that class.  Also... same thing with my registration class.. you just feed it the parameters again and the class does everything.  I don't need to be manipulating my classes at all with scripts.

Good practice or bad practice?  I want to be a professional and I want to start coding like one, but maybe I'm doing it OK?

Comment: You mihgt not want to elicit debate, but there are several situations where this is either good or bad practice, so it will be a debate.

Comment: If you're asking whether you should define classes that have one method that "does everything" that sort of defeats the purpose of Object-oriented programming. Each method should have a specific purpose, and be used for that purpose. Referring to your example, if you're defining a class that does one thing, you might want to reevaluate your design. Instead of having a `login` class, consider having a `user` class with a `login()` method.

Comment: You are describing what OOP is actually about. Hide your information (keep stuff private) and let methods do the work so that a user does not have to care how the work is done. However your constructor should *construct* an object and not do other work.

Comment: Well I hope this question doesn't get closed cus I really need help as I move forward... I need to know the opinions of professionals whether I'm doing things ok or bad, i got a few big projects to work on with other pro's and i don't want to be ridiculed

Comment: Hey matt1, I have alot of methods inside my class that do whatever I need, i just don't need to be calling them or doing anything outside the script, all i do is instantiate the class... and fdomig, that sounds promising i guess im doing it how oop is built to work.. my log in script is just $login = new LogIn($username, $password); thats it, everything is taken care of inside the class

Comment: Since your object is useless, why have a constructor at all? Go procedural, it seems to fit just right.

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close this since it will probably spark a relatively useless debate.

Anyway, there are two big theories on constructors: single stage and multiple stage.  You're doing single stage.  Many people argue for single stage.  However, I think it's bad practice.  Why?

Because it makes it more difficult to test.  When you write tests you want to test individual functionality of an object .. but if your constructor does *everything* that becomes impossible.

It also makes it harder to reuse the object for a different purpose later.  Your object may do everything you need it to do except for one extra method call in the constructor -- so now you have to rewrite it a bit and change how it's called in at least a couple places.

The *real* answer is do what you're most comfortable with in the confines of your project.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.. Great points on testing and object reuse

Answer (score 2):

The method `__construct` should only instantiate (validate/prepare values for instantiation) object and nothing else. That's all. It's not logical that your class do all the work in the constructor.

**EDIT:**
Good practice:

```
Application app = new Application(context); // create application
app.run(); // run it
```

Bad practice:

```
new Application(context) // create & run application
```

Comment: What do you mean by validate/prepare?  You lost me there, but otherwise it makes sense what you are saying

Comment: @JuanVeliz when you create an object usally you pass some parameters to the constructor. So you should be sure that this parameters are valid, if not you can throw an exception. e.g., if you class constructor accepts file resource as parameter, you should check if passed variable is really a resource (with `is_resource` function).

Comment: We're in PHP-land here, so it should be `$app->run()`. (And `$context` too.)

Answer (score 1):

[just my 2 cent]

To be honest, you might as well just use a function for what you describe.

It seems to me you are using your Class as a collection of functions/functionality.

This is OK, and it makes your code more structured, but you don't really use the power of OOP.

The real power of OOP isn't only the fact that you can bundle functions conceptually (which can also be done with appropriate include files that hold conceptual related functions), but the real power of OOP lies more in the fact that you can subclass useful existing Classes.

In my opinion, don't feel forced to go fully OOP if you feel uncomfortable with it. All tasks done with OOP can also be done with procedural approach.
And often, for more mundane tasks, procedural approach is faster to program, and is just as clear as object oriented.

Comment: I used to do 100% procedural everything, and I could do this procedural, but everyone says oop is the future and alot more structured and professional, so I'm just doing procedural in a oop kind of way... Anyway thanks for your opinion it's really good to keep in mind

Comment: People say a lot. I come from Java before PHP, so I know OOP, and I think it isn't appropriate everywhere, especially not in environments where people are not familiar with the OOP approach and are 'forced' to use it. I think you can be totally professional, deliver safe and clean code,  and don't use OOP.
The only problem is that you'll receive 50% of the salary. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This question is along the lines of "is it better to use an integer or a floating point".  Well, it depends on the situation.

What WORKS and what is "standard" are not the same.  If your method works, and for you is easy to debug and maintain, then it's a great solution to use.